# Echo variable out to text file within a subroutine in Batch

Tags: batch-file, echo, subroutine

```
@echo off
Color 1A
TITLE TSM mef3 Extract Script
:start
cls
ECHO.
ECHO        ###################################
ECHO        ##        IAM TSM Extract        ##
ECHO        ##          Version 1.0          ##
ECHO        ##    Written by Kane Charles    ##
ECHO        ###################################
ECHO.
ECHO    Extraction Options:
ECHO.
REM ECHO    1. Extract all Servers
ECHO    2. Extract Server1
ECHO    3. Extract Server2
ECHO    4. Extract Server3
ECHO    4. Extract Server4
ECHO    5. Extract Server5
ECHO    6. Extract Server6
ECHO    7. Extract Server7
ECHO    0. Exit
ECHO.
ECHO    Last Option selected: %selection%
ECHO.
SET/P selection=Please enter a value: 
REM IF %selection%==1 GOTO precommands
IF %selection%==2 call:modifydsmopt 1.2.3.4,1000
IF %selection%==3 call:modifydsmopt 2.3.4.5,1001
IF %selection%==4 call:modifydsmopt 3.4.5.6,1002
IF %selection%==5 call:modifydsmopt 4.5.6.7,1003
IF %selection%==6 call:modifydsmopt 5.6.7.8,1004
IF %selection%==7 call:modifydsmopt 6.7.8.9,1005
IF %selection%==8 call:modifydsmopt 7.8.9.10,1006
IF %selection%==0 exit

pushd C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient

:modifydsmopt
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET IP=%~1
SET PORT=%~2


IF EXIST dsm.opt.bak (
    del dsm.opt.bak
)

IF EXIST dsm.opt (
    ren dsm.opt dsm.opt.bak
)

ECHO commmethod             TCPIP >> dsm.opt
ECHO PASSWORDACCESS         GENERATE >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPSERVERADDRESS       %IP% >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPPORT                %PORT% >> dsm.opt

ECHO IP: %IP%, PORT: %PORT%

rem GOTO EOF
ENDLOCAL


popd

:EOF
```

I've masked the IP addresses and ports for security reasons, obviously they're not real.

The aim of this batch file is to create a fresh `dsm.opt` file that looks like the following:

```
commmethod              TCPIP 
PASSWORDACCESS          GENERATE 
TCPSERVERADDRESS        1.2.3.4 
TCPPORT                 1000
```

**The following two lines do not work:**

```
ECHO TCPSERVERADDRESS       %IP% >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPPORT                %PORT% >> dsm.opt
```

However the following line works fine:

```
ECHO IP: %IP%, PORT: %PORT%
```

So essentially, I can write plain text out to a file, I can echo the variables out to the console, but I can't echo the variables out to a text file.

When run, the subroutine is producing this:

```
commmethod              TCPIP 
PASSWORDACCESS          GENERATE 
TCPSERVERADDRESS     
TCPPORT
```

Can someone please help me with outputting the variables out to a file?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As published, your batch has distinct echoes of attempts to solve problems. I'd suggest you look in `dsm.opt.bak` for the elusive data.

`:modifydsmopt` has unbalanced `setlocal` and `endlocal` as configured, similarly, `popd` and `pushd`

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of `sections` or `procedures` so after `CALL`ing `:modifydsmopt`, execution returns to the instruction following the `call`, ignores the remaining matches on `selection` (because `selection` will not match any of the remaining values) and proceed to the `push`; then re-enter the `:modifydsmopt` subroutine - this time with no parameters, possibly having changed directory (courtesy the `push`) and hence generates a (new?) output file.

The cure is simple.

```
...
IF %selection%==0 exit

:: I've no idea what this change-of-directory is aimed at, so REM it out...
REM pushd C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient

:: We're done - so exit
GOTO :EOF

:modifydsmopt
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET IP=%~1
SET PORT=%~2


IF EXIST dsm.opt.bak (
    del dsm.opt.bak
)

IF EXIST dsm.opt (
    ren dsm.opt dsm.opt.bak
)

ECHO commmethod             TCPIP >> dsm.opt
ECHO PASSWORDACCESS         GENERATE >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPSERVERADDRESS       %IP% >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPPORT                %PORT% >> dsm.opt

ECHO IP: %IP%, PORT: %PORT%

GOTO EOF
```

Note: I've removed the `popd` - possibly you want to move to the directory first, make the changes, then `popd` back - which means the `pushd` should be done **before** `selection` is evaluated **or** is performed in the `:modifydsmopt` routine. Also the `:EOF` label has disappeared - it is not required - `cmd` assumes `goto :EOF` means `go to end-of-file` IMHO, it *should* not be declared. Also, the `goto :eof` (or reaching `EOF`) is an implicit `endlocal`.

What also jumps out is that the `setlocal` and setting of variables appears redundant. Try this:

```
...
IF %selection%==0 exit

:: We're done - so exit
GOTO :EOF

:modifydsmopt
pushd C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient

IF EXIST dsm.opt.bak (
    del dsm.opt.bak
)

IF EXIST dsm.opt (
    ren dsm.opt dsm.opt.bak
)

ECHO commmethod             TCPIP >> dsm.opt
ECHO PASSWORDACCESS         GENERATE >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPSERVERADDRESS       %~1 >> dsm.opt
ECHO TCPPORT                %~2 >> dsm.opt

ECHO IP: %~2, PORT: %~2

POPD

GOTO EOF
```

which will switch to the target directory for the file-manipulation, then switch back. Also not use the variables, so no need to set a local environment.